# Optimize loop over enormous database

Tags: php, mysql

I have to find matches for about 1500 users from a csv file from a database containing about 10 million users. The way I am doing it now is looping through the file and executing a query on each row. But for this amount of users it is exceeding the time limit and crashing. I am not allowed to change the database table in any way and can only make changes to my code.

I was thinking of building a binary tree from the entire table once and then performing the search on the tree instead of on the table.

basically, my code goes like this:

```
//connect to db
//using locator

//loop through csv file and build an array

for ($i = 1; $i < $arraycount; $i++) {
    $email = $csvAsArray[$i][3] ?: "";
    $email2 = $csvAsArray[$i][4] ?: "";
    $myquery = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM user WHERE user_email = :email OR user_email2 = :email2";
    $params = array(':email' => $email,':email2' => $email2);
    $stmt = $db->prepare($myquery);
    $stmt->execute($params);

    if (!$result = $stmt->fetchAll()) {
       //no match
    }
    else{
      // match
    }
}
```

For small files (under 100 rows in CSV), this works fine but this is going to be used mostly by files of over 1000 rows which crashes every time. Any advice on how I could optimize it?

Comment: It may be worth loading the CSV into a staging table and then you can use SQL for matching/checking in 1 go.

Comment: @B001ᛦ I don't have the email I'm looking for until I get to the row in the loop. How would I use the IN statement in that situation and how would it make it faster?

Comment: Because you could fetch it all at once malaria. You absolutely do have all of the emails you're looking for already

Comment: @NigelRen Do you mean I create a temporary table with the data from the CSV file and compare that table to the original one to get the matches?

Comment: @Shardj I am actually looking for emails, phone numbers, names and more. This is just my minimal example code. A match would be by email, phone, or full name and zipcode. Depending on what I have in that specific row, I choose which query to run.

Comment: In that case I'd recommend you generate a single transaction to be run in your loop and don't fetch anything until after the loop.

Comment: @Shardj do you mean I should build the query in the loop and then run the new huge query just once?

Comment: Yes - load the CSV to a table, perhaps add a matchid column and populate it with various SQL statements.  You would also then have a simple query of if the matchid is null then nothing is found.

Comment: @NigelRen I will give that a try thank you

Comment: @malaria yes pretty much

Comment: Is this in a browser or CLI? Btw I would use this lib https://github.com/box/spout  " Contrary to other file readers or writers, it is capable of processing very large files while keeping the memory usage really low (less than 3MB)."

Comment: @delboy1978uk it is in a browser. I am currently using:                                         if (!$fp2 = fopen($tmpName, 'r')) {
            throw new \RuntimeException('Failed to open file "' . $tmpName . '" for reading.');
        }
        $csvAsArray = array();

        while (!feof($fp2) && $line = fgetcsv($fp2)) {
            $csvAsArray[] = $line;
        }
        fclose($fp2);

Comment: BTW, You should put the `$myquery = "SELECT...` and `$stmt = $db->prepare($myquery);` lines **OUTSIDE** of the loop, and `execute` the same prepared statement multiple times inside the loop, don't prepare the same query again and again

Comment: @AlonEitan this is just a minimal example, the query changes on each loop depending on the information I have in the specific row.

Comment: If you can't load the data from your CSV into a table and run single queries (as others have suggested), you can process the CSV in manageable chunks instead of all at once. Upload the file in the first request, then use ajax requests to page through the file until all rows have been processed. Use ftell and fseek to read only the chunk of the file you're interested in on each iteration. You can tune the records processed per request as needed.